# Only Show Divs When Hovering Button for X Time - Can't make it work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

So I'm making a menu that shows various divs when you hover over the menu buttons, but the problem is that the events fire immediately as you hover over the buttons, which I don't want, because if you slide the mouse over more than one button, then they all fire at once and show / hide the div containers (looks bad).

I want the events to fire only if the user hovers the buttons for a certain amount of time, like 500ms, because that way they will only see one div container at a time.

**This is the code I'm using, e.g. for the menu button:**

```
$(".menu-button").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To prevent default anchor tag behaviour
    e.stopPropagation(); //To prevent parent container click event from firing

    $(".menu-container").delay(300).slideDown(800);

});


var myTimer = false;

$(".menu-button, .menu-container").hover(function(){

    //mouse enter
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
},function(){
    //mouse leav
  myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
         $(".menu-container").slideUp(500);
    },100)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g0Lraec/5/

It's driving me nuts, I hope someone can help me out!

Thank you :-)

Comment: Post your HTML code or make jsFiddle - so we can help you

Comment: Actually there is "no HTML" since this is on a WordPress block. It's just block containers with a div class, which I target with JS..    But if you think it will make a difference, I can try making a custom HTML example!

Comment: Okay here is the Fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/1g0Lraec/5/  All I need to know is how to only fire the event if the hover is on the menu button for more than e.g. 500ms.  Right now if you move your mouse quickly over it, it shows the container, even if it's just a split second hover.

Comment: Hmm I think I managed to solve it myself.. I spent like 10 hours on this and all of a sudden I think I got to work, http://jsfiddle.net/1g0Lraec/7/  Would you mind checking if the code is solid? I'm pretty new at this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var upTimer = false ,
downTimer = false ,
isHover = false ;

$(".menu-button, .menu-container").hover(function(){
    isHover = true;
    clearTimeout(upTimer);

    downTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(isHover)
        $(".menu-container").slideDown(500);
    },500);

},function(){

    isHover = false;
    clearTimeout(downTimer);


    upTimer = setTimeout(function(){
         $(".menu-container").slideUp(500);
    },100);

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1g0Lraec/6/)**

This will work also :

```
var downTimer = false

$(".menu-button, .menu-container").hover(function(){

    downTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".menu-container").slideDown(500);
    },500);

},function(){
    clearTimeout(downTimer);
    $(".menu-container").slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: I managed to solve it on my own, but I actually think your first code snippet is cleaner than my own, so I think I'll go with it, thank you!  

Your second snippet however doesn't work for my menu, because the menu container slides up as soon as the mouse leaves the menu button, the menu container has to remain open so people can click on it's items etc. :-) 

Cheers!

Comment: Yes I understand , second code is shorter but will close the menu quickly